# Web page that automatically redirect to EXPO url (exp://...)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, react-native, expo

I am trying to automatically redirect from a webpage to my expo app that has a link with a custom scheme (exp://)

**What I tried:**

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Trigger Click on a Link</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function doSomething(){
    window.location.replace('exp://exp.host/@community/native-component-list');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("a")[0].click();
        },1000)
});
</script>
</head> 
<body>
    <p><a href="#random" onclick="doSomething()">Press me</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**What I expected:**

Automatic redirection to my app

**What happens:**

Automatic redirection doesn't work but the button does

Comment: Console.log window.location variables

Comment: Trying to run it here, but neither the button nor the auto redirect work. I get this error in the console Failed to launch 'exp://exp.host/@community/native-component-list' because the scheme does not have a registered handler

Comment: @PhilCowan button is working only on phone and if you have expo app installed

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS https://imgur.com/a/icGCsAv